# Memory Randomization in Linux

Tags: memory, stack, aslr

I created a simple C program and every time I load it in GDB, I see the same memory addresses allocated to the instructions of the program. For example, a function `what()` always loads at memory location 0x000055555555472d. In fact the stack is exactly the same for each execution(Not just the content of stack but the memory address which rsp points to.

I understand that ASLR can be disabled in Linux by setting "/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space" to 0 but my Debian system has value 2 in it.

```
root@Sierra ~ % cat /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space 
2
```

According to my understanding of ASLR, these addresses should be randomized at each run. 
My question is why is this happening? Did I get something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, gdb disables address space randomization on Linux, overriding whatever value the `kernel.randomize_va_space` sysctl variable may have.

The gdb command [`set disable-randomization off`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html#index-set-disable_002drandomization) will turn this feature off, and any debugging targets created by gdb afterwards will have ASLR either on or off depending on the value of `kernel.randomize_va_space`.

Answer (score 1):

How was the program compiled? On a Centos 7 system given `blah.c` and with the development foo installed

```
#include <stdio.h>

int whereisthis(void) { return 42; }

int main(void) {
    printf("%p\n", whereisthis);
    return 0;
}
```

the address of `whereisthis` can depend on the compile flags

```
% rm blah
% CFLAGS='-pipe' make blah
cc -pipe    blah.c   -o blah
% repeat 3 ./blah
0x40054c
0x40054c
0x40054c
% rm blah
% CFLAGS='-fstack-protector-all -fPIE -pie -pipe' make blah
cc -fstack-protector-all -fPIE -pie -pipe    blah.c   -o blah
% repeat 3 ./blah
0x7f0e9d3ba82f
0x7fd940aca82f
0x7f6961b1182f
%
```